# diffefentiation of (1/2)*(x-y)^2 on x is x - y

Tags: coq

I want to prove following.

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
Require Import Coquelicot.Coquelicot.

Goal forall x y:R, is_derive (fun x:R => (1/2)*(x-y)^2) x (x-y).
intros x y.
evar (e:R).
replace (x-y) with e.
apply is_derive_scal.
apply is_derive_pow.
```

I know that differentiation of `x - y` on x is `1`, but I can not find the lemma which represents it.

How do I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the tedious work can be done with Coquelicot's `auto_derive` tactic.

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
Require Import Coquelicot.Coquelicot.
Require Import Lra.
       
Goal forall x y:R, is_derive (fun x:R => (1/2)*(x-y)^2) x (x-y).

  intros.
  auto_derive.
  auto.
  lra.
Qed.
```

However, the lemma that you are asking for can be built from `is_derive_plus`, because subtraction is just addition with negative values.

```
Variables x y:R.
Check is_derive_plus (fun x => x) (fun x => - y) x 1 0 (is_derive_id _) (is_derive_const _ _) 
     : is_derive (fun x => x - y)  x (1+0).
```